# How can I set username validation on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am newbie on Rails, I build a book sharing platform and I want to set username from e-mail's name. And validation is username must minimum 5 and maximum 50 character. I set it up but validation is not working. The error appears on the screen, but the user can still register. I use Devise for User model and also Devise wiki.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :set_username

  validates :email, presence: true

  has_many :books

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :login

  def login
    @login || self.username || self.email
  end

  private
  def set_username
    self.username = self.email.split('@').first 

    validates_length_of :username, 
    :minimum => 5, :maximum => 50, 
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: true
  end

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      if conditions[:username].nil?
        where(conditions).first
      else
        where(username: conditions[:username]).first
      end
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
  resources :dashboard
  resources :books do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :users
  match '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'
  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'dashboard/index'
  get 'users/index'
end
```

devise/registiration/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the first part of the email address as a username by adding the following to `user.rb`:

```
  def username
    email.split(/@/).first
  end
```

This way for a user with the email `alex@example.com` when you call `user.username` or `current_user.username` you will get `alex`.

You do not need to add a `username` column to your database and you don't need to add validations to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation needs to be in the class and not in the `set_username` method similar to what you do with the presence validation.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates_length_of :username, 
    :minimum => 5, :maximum => 50, 
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: Yes you're right but actually I want to use the e-mail name as username. If I use like that the error expands, and if I enter 5 or more than 5 characters I still get "Username must be more than 5 characters" error.